# Adding variable to pointer is diffrent then adding a constant

Tags: c

So I have learned a bit about operating systems, and after building a bootloader and the kernel entry as described [here](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~exr/lectures/opsys/10_11/lectures/os-dev.pdf), I came across some weird behavior.

Consider this piece of code

```
#define VIDEO_ADDRESS 0xb8000
unsigned char* vidmem = (unsigned char*) VIDEO_ADDRESS;
int p = 0;
```

Now, if i do this

```
*(vidmem + 0) = 0x30;
```

it prints `0` at the top-left corner as it should, but if I do this

```
*(vidmem + p) = 0x30;
```

it prints it somewhere else!

I have tried changing the type of `p`, and it appears that using an `int` causes the `0` being printed somewhere else (which looks completely unrelated). If I use any other variant of `unsigned` and any other type (char, long, int, short), then I need to set `p = 1` to get the `0` printed at the top-left corner (does it subtract 1?).

I don't understand what is going on here, and any help will be appreciated.

Here is the complete code

```
//kernel.c
#define VIDEO_ADDRESS 0xb8000

int main() {
    unsigned char* vidmem = (unsigned char*) VIDEO_ADDRESS;
    int p = 0;
    *(vidmem + p) = 0x30;
}
```

Here is how I compile my C file

```
gcc -ffreestanding -c screen.c -o screen.o
```

I'm using qemu to run the code (Not sure if it has anything to do with this)

**UPDATE:**

If I use GRUB instead, it works as expected.

Comment: This definitely calls for a [mre].  Where it is well defined in the first place, C arithmetic depends on the types and values of the operands, not (otherwise) on the form of the operand expressions.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to inspect the assembly generated by the two statements.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I did that, and it didn't seem to have any problems (although I'm not very good with assembly, so I might have missed it).. Should I edit my question to include it?

Comment: Adding an `int` variable to a pointer n C is *definitely* the same as adding an `int` constant.  Your second example `*(vidmem + p) = 0x30` absolutely should have behaved the same way, presuming the value of `p` was in fact 0.  There must be something else going on here, that we can't see.

Comment: I would pick a name other than `p` for a variable that's not a pointer, but that's a stylistic point, that won't affect the functionality.

Comment: Is `p` global? if so it's likely in BSS, which might not be getting zeroed. Consider trying to compile it with `-fno-zero-initialized-in-bss` to test it out.

Comment: Where is _"somewhere else"_? Is `p` really `0` when the program is executing `*(vidmem + p) = 0x30;`? Please show a [MCVE], I'm sure there is something you're not telling us.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I edited the question to include the whole code (kernel.c)

Comment: What happens if you use this syntax: `vidmem[p] = 0x30;` ?

Comment: @chqrlie then it produces exactly the same result

Comment: @Hasturkun didn't work

Comment: I am pretty shure your stack pointer is completely b0rked. Probably even so that it is not properly aligned upon entering the function.

Comment: "it didn't seem to have any problems" -- What does that mean? If this is compiled with optimization, the exact same code should be produced by `*(vidmem + 0) = 0x30;` and `int p = 0; *(vidmem + p) = 0x30;`.  "then it produces exactly the same result" -- as what? You have described two different results. In any case, it's unlikely that the difference has anything to do with using `p` or not ... you may be having random results that have coincidentally correlated with the two syntaxes.

Comment: @JimBalter I don't compile with optimization, but if I do, then it works perfectly.

Comment: Optimizing can have the effect that the compiler "sees" that p is anyway 0, so no need to allocate memory for the "useless" variable p. This might be a further hint that somithing is wrong with p resp the address where p is stored. Antti Haapala already mentioned stack pointer. What if you define p above main as a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an answer, but I need to format code.

To debug, try:

```
#define VIDEO_ADDRESS 0xb8000

int main() {
    int p = 0;
    unsigned char* vidmem = (unsigned char*) VIDEO_ADDRESS + p;
    *vidmem = 0x30;
}
```

This might prove Antti Haapala's suspicion.

I also sugested to inspect the assembler generated, and you could step it in the debugger and inspect registers and memory locations, if your platforms has a debugger.

Comment: I agree: Even when Writing a "Simple" Operating System from Scratch some knowledge of the cpu architecture, the machine code resp assembler code and a debugger (preferably a hardware debugger) can not harm.